# mySQL Create Function

Tags: mysql, create-function

Can anyone help work out why this create function isn't working. I've copied it from a a program teaching me mySQL and I've double checked and it doesn't seem to work.
any help greatly appreciated

```
Delimiter//
Create Function CAP_FIX(Input VARChar(255))
Returns varchar(255)
Deterministic
begin
Declare first Char;
Declare remainder varchar(255);
Set first = substring(input,1,1);
Set remainder = substring(input,2,char_length(input) -1);
Return concat(first, lower(remainder));
end//
Delimiter;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"? Are you getting any error?

Comment: Could you give us some error logs and also the structure of the database so we can see if something is missing or going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if you're missing a space after `Delimiter`

```
Delimiter //
Create Function FUNCTION_NAME (Input VARChar(255))
Returns varchar(255)
Deterministic
begin
Declare first Char;
Declare remainder varchar(255);
Set first = substring(input,1,1);
Set remainder = substring(input,2,char_length(input) -1);
Return concat(first, lower(remainder));
end//
Delimiter ;
```